# Get all files recursively in directories NodejS

Tags: node.js, fs, getfiles

I have a little problem with my function. I would like to get all files in many directories. Currently, I can retrieve the files in the file passed in parameters. I would like to retrieve the html files of each folder in the folder passed as a parameter. I will explain if I put in parameter "test" I retrieve the files in "test" but I would like to retrieve "test / 1 / *. Html", "test / 2 / *. /*.html ":

```
var srcpath2 = path.join('.', 'diapo', result);
function getDirectories(srcpath2) {
                return fs.readdirSync(srcpath2).filter(function (file) {
                    return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath2, file)).isDirectory();
                });
            }
```

The result :
[1,2,3]

thanks !

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It looks like the [`glob` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) would help you. Here is an example of how to use it:

File hierarchy:

```
test
├── one.html
└── test-nested
    └── two.html
```

JS code:

```
const glob = require("glob");

var getDirectories = function (src, callback) {
  glob(src + '/**/*', callback);
};
getDirectories('test', function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

which displays:

```
[ 'test/one.html',
  'test/test-nested',
  'test/test-nested/two.html' ]
```

Comment: **the shortest way** i found

Comment: I was little disappointed that glob will skip Dot Files. What is the purpose of this package if we cannot get dotfiles with simple search?

Comment: @AsifAshraf per the documentation: `You can make glob treat dots as normal characters by setting dot:true in the options.` -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Comment: @Paul Mougel The question mentions to get all the "FILES" you are also returning the FOLDERS. Please provide another solution to get only the list of files using glob.

Comment: With [dree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dree) you can achieve something very similar

Answer (score 81):

I've seen many very long answers, and it's kinda a waste of memory space. Some also use packages like `glob`, but if you don't want to depend on any package, here's my solution.

```js
const Path = require("path");
const FS   = require("fs");
let Files  = [];

function ThroughDirectory(Directory) {
    FS.readdirSync(Directory).forEach(File => {
        const Absolute = Path.join(Directory, File);
        if (FS.statSync(Absolute).isDirectory()) return ThroughDirectory(Absolute);
        else return Files.push(Absolute);
    });
}

ThroughDirectory("./input/directory/");
```

It's pretty self-explanatory. There's an input directory, and it iterates through that. If one of the items is also a directory, go through that and so on. If it's a file, add the absolute path to the array.

Hope this helped :]

Comment: const fetchAllFilesFromGivenFolder = (fullPath) => {
  let files = [];

  fs.readdirSync(fullPath).forEach(file => {
    const absolutePath = path.join(fullPath, file);
    if (fs.statSync(absolutePath).isDirectory()) {
      const filesFromNestedFolder = fetchAllFilesFromGivenFolder(absolutePath);
      filesFromNestedFolder.forEach(file => {
        files.push(file);
      })
    }
    else return files.push(absolutePath);
  });

  return files
}

Comment: The `Files` is a global variable, we can improve the solution by taking a `Files` variable or return the top level results

Answer (score 45):

Using ES6 yield

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function *walkSync(dir) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
  for (const file of files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      yield* walkSync(path.join(dir, file.name));
    } else {
      yield path.join(dir, file.name);
    }
  }
}

for (const filePath of walkSync(__dirname)) {
  console.log(filePath);
}
```

Comment: never heard of this syntax and keyword

Comment: @GorvGoyl this is generator function, learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_generators#generator_functions

Answer (score 39):

I really liked Smally's Solution but didn't like the Syntax.

Same solution but slightly easier to read:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
let files = [];

const getFilesRecursively = (directory) => {
  const filesInDirectory = fs.readdirSync(directory);
  for (const file of filesInDirectory) {
    const absolute = path.join(directory, file);
    if (fs.statSync(absolute).isDirectory()) {
        getFilesRecursively(absolute);
    } else {
        files.push(absolute);
    }
  }
};
```

**2023 Update**

Node v18+ (LTS) offers a [recursive flag for readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options). So you should probably use that. [EOL for v16](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/nodejs16-eol) is September 2023 btw.

```
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  const files = await readdir('./', { recursive: true });
  console.log(files);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: I used your snippet and works very well. Thank you and Smally ;)

Answer (score 16):

Here's mine. Like all good answers it's hard to understand:

```
const isDirectory = path => statSync(path).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = path =>
    readdirSync(path).map(name => join(path, name)).filter(isDirectory);

const isFile = path => statSync(path).isFile();  
const getFiles = path =>
    readdirSync(path).map(name => join(path, name)).filter(isFile);

const getFilesRecursively = (path) => {
    let dirs = getDirectories(path);
    let files = dirs
        .map(dir => getFilesRecursively(dir)) // go through each directory
        .reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []);    // map returns a 2d array (array of file arrays) so flatten
    return files.concat(getFiles(path));
};
```

Comment: Good answers are usually the most simple to understand

Comment: This answer is well written and not that hard to understand. It works. It is not a lot of code. It is synchronous, unlike glob.

Comment: Instead of `statSync` now you can load all stats in one call. `const dirs = await readdir('./', { withFileTypes: true })`

Answer (score 9):

With modern JavaScript (NodeJs 10) you can use async generator function and loop through them using [for-await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

```
// ES modules syntax that is included by default in NodeJS 14.
// For earlier versions, use `--experimental-modules` flag
import fs from "fs/promises"

// or, without ES modules, use this:
// const fs = require('fs').promises

async function run() {
  for await (const file of getFiles()) {
    console.log(file.path)
  }
}

async function* getFiles(path = `./`) {
  const entries = await fs.readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true })

  for (let file of entries) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      yield* getFiles(`${path}${file.name}/`)
    } else {
      yield { ...file, path: path + file.name }
    }
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: To make this faster, switch the first loop to `await getFiles().forEach((file) => ...` and the second loop to `for(let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)`.

Comment: Why would that be faster? It would take longer to get first result. It would also take more memory. Please back up this claim with a benchmark.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer needs to install a package.
If you want a native option that is ES6:

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'

function walk(dir) {
  return readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true }).flatMap((file) => file.isDirectory() ? walk(join(dir, file.name)) : join(dir, file.name))
}
```

This works for me.

- Read root directory with `readdirSync`
- Then map over but `flatten` as we go
- if it's a directory, go recursive; else return the filename

Comment: great solution, deserves its own npm package

Answer (score 6):

Packed into library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-recursive-directory

https://github.com/vvmspace/node-recursive-directory

**List of files:**

```js
const getFiles = require('node-recursive-directory');

(async () => {
    const files = await getFiles('/home');
    console.log(files);
})()
```

**List of files with parsed data:**

```js
const getFiles = require('node-resursive-directory');
 
(async () => {
    const files = await getFiles('/home', true); // add true
    console.log(files);
})()
```

*You will get something like that:*

```js
  [
      ...,
      {
        fullpath: '/home/vvm/Downloads/images/Some/Some Image.jpg',
        filepath: '/home/vvm/Downloads/images/Some/',
        filename: 'Some Image.jpg',
        dirname: 'Some'
    },
  ]
```

Comment: For me, just running the require crashes nodemon.

Comment: There's a typo @JCraine. It should be recursive

Answer (score 3):

Node.js v20 added a `recursive` option to the `readdir()` method. So assuming you have the directory as the first answer(** Paul Mougel
**):

```
└── test
    ├── one.html
    └── test-nested
        └── two.html
```

You can do it succinctly as follows without any dependency:

```
const { readdir } = require("node:fs/promises");

async function getFiles(dir) {
  const files = await readdir(dir, { recursive: true });
  const entries = files.map((filename) => `${dir}/${filename}`);
  console.log(entries);
}
getFiles("test);
```

The output will look as follows:

```
[ 'test/one.html', 'test/test-nested', 'test/test-nested/two.html' ]
```

Comment: This Script only shows parent folder, and child folders not the files inside each child folder, for me the answer from @FakeFootball was the right one to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write your own code like below to traverse the directory as shown below :

```
var fs = require('fs');
function traverseDirectory(dirname, callback) {
  var directory = [];
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, list) {
    dirname = fs.realpathSync(dirname);
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var listlength = list.length;
    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = dirname + '\\' + file;
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        directory.push(file);
 if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          traverseDirectory(file, function(err, parsed) {
     directory = directory.concat(parsed);
     if (!--listlength) {
       callback(null, directory);
     }
   });
 } else {
     if (!--listlength) {
       callback(null, directory);
     }
          }
      });
    });
  });
}
traverseDirectory(__dirname, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

You can check more information about it here : http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/09/how-to-navigate-through-directories-in.html

Comment: thanks ! but how send the result in res.send ? please

Comment: @coco62 Once you get the result inside the function, you can pass that instead of logging it.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to so something similar, in an Electron app: get all subfolders in a given base folder, using TypeScript, and came up with this:

```
import { readdirSync, statSync, existsSync } from "fs";
import * as path from "path";

// recursive synchronous "walk" through a folder structure, with the given base path
getAllSubFolders = (baseFolder, folderList = []) => {

    let folders:string[] = readdirSync(baseFolder).filter(file => statSync(path.join(baseFolder, file)).isDirectory());
    folders.forEach(folder => {
        folderList.push(path.join(baseFolder,folder));
        this.getAllSubFolders(path.join(baseFolder,folder), folderList);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var filesCollection = [];
const directoriesToSkip = ['bower_components', 'node_modules', 'www', 'platforms'];

function readDirectorySynchronously(directory) {
    var currentDirectorypath = path.join(__dirname + directory);

    var currentDirectory = fs.readdirSync(currentDirectorypath, 'utf8');

    currentDirectory.forEach(file => {
        var fileShouldBeSkipped = directoriesToSkip.indexOf(file) > -1;
        var pathOfCurrentItem = path.join(__dirname + directory + '/' + file);
        if (!fileShouldBeSkipped && fs.statSync(pathOfCurrentItem).isFile()) {
            filesCollection.push(pathOfCurrentItem);
        }
        else if (!fileShouldBeSkipped) {
            var directorypath = path.join(directory + '\\' + file);
            readDirectorySynchronously(directorypath);
        }
    });
}

readDirectorySynchronously('');
```

This will fill **filesCollection** with all the files in the directory and its subdirectories (it's recursive). You have the option to skip some directory names in the **directoriesToSkip** array.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of npm packages - another short option is to use [fs-readdir-recursive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-readdir-recursive):

```js
const read = require("fs-readdir-recursive");
const foundFiles = read("test");
console.log(foundFiles);
```

Output:

```
[ 'one.html', 'test-nested/some_text.txt', 'test-nested/two.html' ]
```

If you're interested only in files with specific extension (like .html mentioned in the question) you can filter them using `.endsWith()`:

```
const filteredFiles = read("test").filter(item => item.endsWith(".html"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified version of @Stephen's response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083078/4421370) above that returns the files' path relative to the directory you are searching. Or any arbitrary base path you supply to the function call in-place of the default base. If you want the full path just call it as `walkSync(dir, dir)`.

Search Path is: `c:\tmp`,
File path is `c:\tmp\test\myfile.txt`,
Result is `test\myfile.txt`

Hopefully helpful to some.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function *walkSync(dir, base="") {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
  for (const file of files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      yield* walkSync(path.join(dir, file.name), path.join(base, file.name));
    } else {
      yield path.join(base, file.name);
    }
  }
}

for (const filePath of walkSync(__dirname)) {
   console.log(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Your link to the Slightly modified version of @_Stephen's response returns me to this post, (The current post) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462606/get-all-files-recursively-in-directories-nodejs/66083078#66083078 without any news about @Stephen's response

Answer (score 1):

If you rather work synchronously with glob, use the `glob.sync()` function as mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options). Here's the equivalent example provided by @Paul Mougel but written synchronously:

```
const glob = require("glob");

var getDirectories = function (src) {
  return glob.sync(src + '/**/*');
};
var rest = getDirectories('test');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with Promises based on [globby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globby):

```js
import { globby } from 'globby';

(async () => {
  const path = '/path/to/dir';
  const files = await globby([`${path}/**/*`]);

  console.log(files);
  // [ 
  //   '/path/to/dir/file1.txt', 
  //   '/path/to/dir/subdir/file2.txt', 
  //   ... 
  // ]
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Synchrone method with two option, simple and efficacy.

```
const path = require('path');const fs = require('fs');

    function toHierarchie_files(pathDir, output_normalize=false, removeEmpty=true)
{
   var result = {}, enqueue = [pathDir];
   //normalize slash separator if output_normalize is true or just return val
   output_normalize = output_normalize == false?val => {return val}:val => {return path.normalize(val)};
   
   //allows absolute or relative path with extended resolution. Returns path normalize absolute to work with or 'none' string.
   const path_exist = (path_test) => {var tmpTab = fs.existsSync(path.normalize(path.resolve(path_test))) == true?[path.normalize(path.resolve(path_test))]:['', '../', '../../'].map(val => path.normalize(path.resolve(__dirname, val+path_test))).filter((val, index) => fs.existsSync(path.normalize(path.resolve(__dirname, val+path_test))) == true);return tmpTab.length > 0?tmpTab[0]:'none'};
   //Check if file exist and return her type or 'none' string
   const getType = (path_test) => {path_test = path_exist(path_test);return path_test == 'none'?'none':fs.lstatSync(path_test).isDirectory() == true?'dir':fs.lstatSync(path_test).isFile() == true?'file':'none';};
   
   
   function recursive()
   {
      //init new entrie
      var parentDir = enqueue.pop();result[parentDir]=[];
      //read dir
      fs.readdirSync(path_exist(parentDir)).forEach((file, index) =>{
         switch(getType(parentDir+'/'+file))
         {
            //if detect dir push in queue
            case 'dir': enqueue.push(output_normalize(parentDir+'/'+file)); break;
            //if file, add in entrie
            case 'file': result[parentDir].push(file); break;
            //else done
            default: break;
         };
      });
      //if optional arg remove empty is true, delete entries if not contains files
      if(result[parentDir].length == 0 && removeEmpty == true){Reflect.deleteProperty(result, parentDir);}
      //if queue is not empty continue processing
      if(enqueue.length > 0){recursive();}
   };
   
   //if dir renseign exist, go recusive
   if(getType(pathDir) == 'dir'){recursive();}
   
   return result;
};
```

Result:

```
{
"public/assets": [
    "favicon.ico"
],
"public/assets/js": [
    "dede.js",
    "test.js"
],
"public/assets/js/css/secure": [
    "config.json",
    "index.js"
],
"public/assets/css": [
    "style.css"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop through all the files and directories of the root folder, if it's a directory, then get inside it and repeat the process.
Consider the code below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const target = './'; // choose the directory to target
var result = []
var filePaths = []
var tempFolder = []
const targetPath = fs.readdirSync(target);




function hit(mainPath = targetPath) {

  mainPath.forEach((file) => {

    let check = fs.statSync(file);

    if (!check.isDirectory()) {
      filePaths.push(file)
    }
    else {
      if (file[0] != '.') {
        tempFolder.push(file)
      }
    }
  });

  // get files from folder
  if (tempFolder.length > 0) {
    tempFolder.forEach((dir) => {
      getFiles(dir)
    })
  } 
   // filePaths contains path to every file

}




function getFiles(dir) {

  var paths = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  var files = [];

  paths.forEach(function (file) {
    var fullPath = dir + '/' + file;
    files.push(fullPath);
  });

  files.forEach((tempFile) => {
    let check = fs.statSync(tempFile);

    if (check.isDirectory()) {
      getFiles(tempFile)
    } else {
      filePaths.push(tempFile)
    }
  })
}



hit(); // main function
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not perfect in some scenarios, it must be helpful in many.

```
const getAllFilePath = (path: string) => {
    const addData = (_paths: string[]) => {
        const newFoldersToScrape: string[] = [];

        _paths.forEach(_path => {
            fs.readdirSync(_path).forEach((file: string) => {
                if (file.indexOf(".") === -1) {
                    newFoldersToScrape.push(`${_path}/${file}`);
                } else {
                    filePaths.push(`${_path}/${file}`);
                }
            });
        });

        foldersToScrape = newFoldersToScrape;
    };

    const baseDirPath = `<YOUR BASE PATH HERE>/${path}`;
    let foldersToScrape: string[] = [];
    const filePaths: string[] = [];

    addData([baseDirPath]);

    while (foldersToScrape.length !== 0) {
        addData(foldersToScrape);
    }

    return filePaths;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, I think it is similar to yet simpler than most of the other answers here.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
let files = []

const getFiles = (path) => {
  if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) { // is this a folder?
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(f => {   // for everything in this folder
      getFiles(path + '/' + f)            // process it recursively
    })
  } else if (path.endsWith(".ts")) {  // is this a file we are searching for?
    files.push(path)                  // record it
  }
}

getFiles("src")
```

It fills the "files" array with every .ts file under the "src/" directory.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, using Asynchronous Generators and recursion makes it really elegant

```js
import { opendir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

/**
 * Recursivly yields files from a child directory tree
 * @param path Starting directory path
 */
export async function* dirGenerator(path: string): AsyncGenerator<string, void, void> {
    const dirIterator = await opendir(path)
    for await (const dirent of dirIterator) {
        if (dirent.isDirectory()) {
            yield* dirGenerator(join(path, dirent.name))
        } else {
            yield join(path, dirent.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a compact pure function that returns all the paths (relatives) in the directory.

```js
import path from 'path'

const getFilesPathsRecursively = (directory: string, origin?: string): string[] =>
  fs.readdirSync(directory).reduce((files, file) => {
    const absolute = path.join(directory, file)
    return [
      ...files,
      ...(fs.statSync(absolute).isDirectory()
        ? getFilesPathsRecursively(absolute, origin || directory)
        : [path.relative(origin || directory, absolute)]),
    ]
  }, [])
```

Comment: you have a `ReferenceError: path is not defined`

Comment: @SamSedighian You just need to import it: it is Node's path utility. I edited the answer to add the import.

Answer (score -1):

- The solution is written in TypeScript.
- modern solution with async/await
- No external dependencies.
- Asynchronous function (non-blocking like other solutions with `readdirSync` and `statSync`)
- It is extremely fast because multiple processes work in parallel (it is not waiting for a response from every file in the list).
- It has also some naive error handling (if something happens with one file or folder it will not blow whole process)

```js
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs/promises"

export default async function readDirectory(directory: string): Promise<string[]> {
    const files = await fs.readdir(directory)
    const filesPromises = files.map(async (file) => {
        try {
            const absolutePath = path.join(directory, file);
            const fileStat = await fs.stat(absolutePath)
            if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {

                return await readDirectory(absolutePath);
            } else {
                return absolutePath; 
            }
        } catch (err) {
            // error handling
            return [];
        }
    });
    const filesWithArrays = await Promise.all(filesPromises)
    const flatArray = filesWithArrays.reduce<string[]>((acc, fileOrArray) => acc.concat(fileOrArray), []);
    return flatArray;
}
```

usage (if this is a separate file please remember to import)

```js
const results = await readDirectory('some/path');
```

Answer (score -2):

I did mine with typescript works well fairly easy to understand

```
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    import * as path from 'path';

    export const getAllSubFolders = (
      baseFolder: string,
      folderList: string[] = []
    ) => {
      const folders: string[] = fs
        .readdirSync(baseFolder)
        .filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(baseFolder, file)).isDirectory());
      folders.forEach(folder => {
        folderList.push(path.join(baseFolder, folder));
        getAllSubFolders(path.join(baseFolder, folder), folderList);
      });
      return folderList;
    };
    export const getFilesInFolder = (rootPath: string) => {
      return fs
        .readdirSync(rootPath)
        .filter(
          filePath => !fs.statSync(path.join(rootPath, filePath)).isDirectory()
        )
        .map(filePath => path.normalize(path.join(rootPath, filePath)));
    };
    export const getFilesRecursively = (rootPath: string) => {
      const subFolders: string[] = getAllSubFolders(rootPath);
      const allFiles: string[][] = subFolders.map(folder =>
        getFilesInFolder(folder)
      );
      return [].concat.apply([], allFiles);
    };
```

Comment: I had some trouble with typescript+eslint and the flattening of the array in the last lines.
So I replaced the last steps by array.reduce. Since we can't post multiline code in comments, here's a single-liner :) `export const getFilesRecursively = (rootPath: string) => getAllSubFolders(rootPath).reduce((result, folder) => [...result, ...getFilesInFolder(folder)], [] as string[])`