# return an array from glob node js

Tags: node.js, glob, fs, getfiles

**The issue**

I'm using the answer here [Get all files recursively in directories NodejS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462606/get-all-files-recursively-in-directories-nodejs/41462807#41462807)
however, when I assign it to a constant I'm trying to return the directories so I can have them available in an array, I have looked through globs documentation for an asnwer https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob, however I have had no successful results, I have tried using glob.end() and I have also console.log the **folds** variable below, I can see all the list of available methods and I have tried to use some of them with no success, does anyone know how to return the array like in the code example below? Thank you!

```
 const glob = require('glob');
 const src = 'assets';


function getFiles(err, res){
  if (err) {
   console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
  return res
  }
}

let folds =  glob(src + '/**/*', getFiles);
```

Comment: Where is `src` set, also your callback function does not receive `err `or `res`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone editing mistake

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

`glob()` is asynchronous and that can make returning the end result somewhat complicated.

Use `glob.sync()` instead (where `.sync` stands for synchronous)

Example:

```js
const files = glob.sync(src + '/**/*');
```