# How can I read a file in node js, find all instances of a function and then extract each function's argument?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to write a node script that identifies unused translation strings in my React project.

First, I want to get a list of all the translations that *are* used. To do this, I am getting a list of each JS file in my `/src/components` folder and then reading the file.

My translation strings look like this: `t('some.translation.key')`, so basically, I want to identify each instance of `t('...')` using RegEx and then get the key in between those parentheses (i.e. "some.translation.key"). From there, I should be able to compare the keys to the ones in my translation JSON file and remove the ones that aren't being used.

**unused.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
let files = [];

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111390/2262604
function getFiles(dir) {
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    const absolute = path.join(dir, file);

    if (fs.statSync(absolute).isDirectory()) {
      getFiles(absolute);
    } else {
      if (absolute.includes('.js')) {
        files.push(absolute);
      }
    }
  });
  return files;
}

function getTranslations() {
  const pathComponents = path.join(__dirname, '../../src/components');

  // get all js files in components directory
  const files = getFiles(pathComponents);

  const translationKeys = [];

  // for each js file
  for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // read contents of file
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(files[i]).toString();

    // search contents for all instances of t('...')
    // and get the key between the parentheses

  }
}

getTranslations();
```

How can I use RegEx to find all instances of `t('...')` in `contents` and then extract the `...` string between the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you *could* use a regular expression:

```js
for (const [, str] of contents.matchAll(/\bt\(['"](.*?)['"]\)/g)) {
  console.log('t called with string argument:', str)
}
```

However, with regular expressions the problem will be that they don't *understand* the code and would cause trouble with matching strings that contain `( )` or `\'` themselves, have issues with concatenated strings or extra whitespace, etc., and you'd then also get the contents literally, including possible escape sequences.

A more robust way would be to create an AST ([abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) from the code and look for calls to `t` in it.

A popular AST parser would be [acorn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn). There is also the supplementary module [acorn-walk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn-walk) that helps walking through the whole syntax tree without building your own recursive algorithm.

```js
import acorn from 'acorn'
import walk from 'acorn-walk'

// Example
const contents = "function a () { if (123) { t('hello') } return t('world') }"

// The arguments to acorn.parse would have to be adjusted based
// on what kind of syntax your files can use.
const result = acorn.parse(contents, {ecmaVersion: 2020})

walk.full(result, node => {
  if (node.type === 'CallExpression' && node.callee.type === 'Identifier' && node.callee.name === 't') {
    if (node.arguments.length === 1 && node.arguments[0].type === 'Literal' && typeof node.arguments[0].value === 'string') {
      // This is for the case `t` is called with a single string
      // literal as argument.
      console.log('t called with string argument:', node.arguments[0].value)
    } else {
      // In case you have things like template literals as well,
      // or multiple arguments, you'd need to handle them here too.
      console.log('t called with unknown arguments:', node.arguments)
    }
  }
})

// Will output:
//   t called with string argument: hello
//   t called with string argument: world
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! This helps a lot. In my case, I'm using React and JSX, so I needed the `acorn-jsx` and `acorn-jsx-walk` packages. I also needed `sourceType: 'module'` as a `parser` option to use `require()`. With those in place, I'm off to the races!

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for (finding translations with t()), but acorn doesn't seem to support TSX. Any idea what I could do?